# jquery dialog changes it's dom location upon being shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, iframe, modal-dialog

I have the following structure of my web-page

[image: page_structure]

It consists of several `iframe` elements. Top `iframe` has a button, when user presses it I want to show `modal dialog` upon the whole entire page (not inside the top `iframe`).
So, I'm using the following code to create and append `dialog` element dynamically:

```
var context = findMainWindow();//returns the main page window, out of scope
var modalDialog = $('body', context.document).append('<div id="' + dialogName + '" />').find('#' + dialogName);
```

This code works and  I see the element gets injected into dom of main page:

[image: div_injected]

Then I call `.dialog` method to show it:

```
  $modalDialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            height: h,
            width: w,
            resizable: false,
            close: function () {
                $modalDialog.dialog('destroy');
                $modalDialog.remove();
            }
        });
```

, but instead of showing it upon the entire page it moves the element into the dom of the iframe, where the initial button resides. Here is the illustration:

[image]

How to make it show upon the body of the whole page, where element belonged after injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters same behavior - it was just a bug in jquery-ui. Upgrade to latest version solved the issue.